# Different content-types in the same script

Tags: python

I need to use different content-types in a Python script and I would like to know how to 'reset' the content-type after I used 'text/html' for example.
Here an example that is not working like I would expect

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "Hello! I'm going to redirect"
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print "Refresh: 0; url=http://www.stackoverflow.com\n"
```

Comment: How is this code being executed? Is it a CGI script?

Comment: @sharth: Yes, in CGI way.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: it's printed all as html. I mean it's displayed Hello...stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

A CGI script will be run separately for each request. So figure out which page is being requested, and then only send the correct content type.

Comment: Looking at that example, how is it possible to make work in that way (just a script)?